# Stack overflow in a child thread blocks parent thread

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC application. In my controller, I am performing XSLT transformation. I have a transformation that is causing stack overflow exception, shutting my whole (VS-hosted) server down.

I know what is wrong with my transformation, so I do not want to fix it (I'll do it later), for now I want to be able to correctly handle scenarios where a stack overflow causes unpredicated behavior. My idea is to create a new child thread, and in this thread process the XSLT, if the thread runs for too long, I would like to kill it in the parent thread.

Now that's for theory, in practice, when I do this, parent thread gets locked out, debugger is not moving forward and everything crashes. Below is **one of many** examples of code that I have tried - I tried `Task.Run()` and `CancellationToken` approach, I tried it with `Task.Wait(1000)`, I tried `new Thread(()=>MyFunction())` approach, I tried calling `xslt.Transform()` as you see below, but I also tried to wrap 100% of transformation codebase in a separate method, pass immutable props to it and have 100% of activity to happen on that thread. I tried cross-referencing variables (as you see below with `transformedMessage = (...)`), I tried returning transformed message and awaiting for it from Task / Joining a thread. Lastly, I also tried `for` loop with a `Thread.Sleep` on parent thread, to see if I can manually abort that child thread after few loops.

I tried a lot, and none of my approaches work - Visual Studio always, first hangs for few minutes, then throws stack overflow exception on that `xslt.Transform` - I am definitely missing something here in my approach.

A long post, so here is the question: **Why does a child thread with a stack overflow exception blocks parent thread from continuing being processed**? Perhaps it has something to do with .Net core/MVC and the way VS built in server handles things? Is this a bug in VS/.Net core, or I am unaware of something when it comes to parallel processing?

```
using (var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(1000)) {
    try {
        var token = tokenSource.Token;
        var task = Task.Run(()=>{
            xslt.Transform(xri, args, xwo);
            transformedMessage = sw.ToString();
        }, token);
        await task; //don't focus on this, it's just one of many versions I have tried, debugger does not even reach this point
    } catch (TaskCanceledException) {
        throw new TimeoutException("Timeout");
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix your stack overflow. Threads that get killed because of one may hold on to resources that never get released (as you've found).

Comment: The stack is not per thread. It is shared. If you have a stackoverflow, it doesn’t occur on one thread. It occurs on the memory. When the other thread also doesn’t have any space, it also cannot run.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b: That's not correct, actually: each thread does indeed have its own stack.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to fix my stack overflow issue, what I don't know, is how to be able to handle it serverside. My thinking is, that it must be doable to send this code to a separate thread/processing flow, without locking MVC thread - otherwise my whole windows would freeze? What if I spawn a new `Process()`? Though process way is very ugly and I don't want to go this route.

Comment: Processes are completely isolated from one another, and any (rare) cross-process references, like named mutexes, are cleaned up by the O/S when one terminates, so you should be safe doing that.

Comment: In my world a StackoverflowException isn't catchable and ends the process. And its still documented that way. Putting that stuff in a different process sounds like a solution for that just inferior to fixing the Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do not mean "unpredicated".  Maybe you meant "undefined"?  or "unpredictable"?

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow exceptions are unrecoverable exceptions. You cannot handle it, and  need to fix that issue. You can spawn new threads to avoid the stack overflow in the first place, but stackoverflows are terminal and crash the process.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated stack overflows are special. You need to fix the root cause.  Here's what [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception?view=net-7.0) have to say about it...

*Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, you can't catch a StackOverflowException object with a try/catch block, and the corresponding process is terminated by default. Consequently, you should write your code to detect and prevent a stack overflow.*